# How pass an object from controller to view with asp.net (motor aspx not razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, controller

I need to pass an object from my controller to my view, I have the next code

```
public ActionResult General(int id)
    {
        List<Topics> topics = new List<Topics>();
        Topics top = new Topics();
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        topics = top.getAllTopics(id);
        for (int i = 0; i < topics.Count; i++)
        {

            items.Add(topics[i].name);

        }
        ViewBag.Items = items; 
        return View(topics.Count);
    }
```

and I need use the value of `topics.Count` in my view and  putting it in a for.

Comment: How is your view look like ? You may get sample on web.

Comment: "motor aspx"? Not sure what exactly you mean.

Comment: Side note: there is no point of assigning value to `topics = new List<Topic>();` as you immediately overwriting it (but I assume you know it and just combined random lines as sample, still may be good ide to fix it up).

Comment: i did mean syntax in motor(engine) aspx, when you use a razor engine, the syntax is different to aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your code to this

```
public ActionResult General(int id)
    {
        List<Topics> topics = new List<Topics>();
        Topics top = new Topics();
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        topics = top.getAllTopics(id);
        for (int i = 0; i < topics.Count; i++)
        {

            items.Add(topics[i].name);

        }
        ViewBag.Items = items;
        ViewBag.Counter = topics.Count; // this line was added
        return View(topics.Count);
    }
```

And in your View add this if your are using Razor syntax

```
@for(var i=0;i<ViewBar.Counter;i++){
  //Do your logic here

}
```

Comment: but if i need pass an object to view, how can i do that?

Comment: Try adding validations. Once you had passed the value to ViewBag.Counter, you need to check the type of object and cast it or try casting it.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a class with Topics as name, and set public properties in the 
  Topics class.
- Create a strong type view with Topics as your model, within this
  view, you can display or edit your properties set in Topics class.
- When you return a view back just return the model, in this case it
  will be return view (Topics).